# Encode a Ruby string to a JSON string

Tags: ruby, string, json, escaping

The `json` gem does not allow for directly encoding strings to their JSON representation. I tentatively ported this PHP code:

```
$text = json_encode($string);
```

to this Ruby:

```
text = string.inspect
```

and it seemed to do the job but for some reason if the `string` itself contains a literal string (it's actually JS code) with newlines, these newlines `\n` will stay as-is `\n`, not be encoded to `\\n`. I can understand if this is the correct behaviour of `#inspect`, but...

How does one encode a string value to its JSON representation in Ruby?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of Ruby 2.1, you can

```
require 'json'

'hello'.to_json
```

Answer (score 24):

This works with the stock 1.9.3+ standard library JSON:

```
require 'json'
JSON.generate('foo', quirks_mode: true) # => "\"foo\""
```

Without `quirks_mode: true`, you get the ridiculous "JSON::GeneratorError: only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed".

Answer (score 3):

There are a myriad of JSON gems for Ruby, some pure Ruby some C-based for better performance.

Here is one that offers both pure-Ruby and C:
http://flori.github.com/json/

And then its essentially:

```
require 'json'
JSON.encode(something)
```

A popular JSON encoder/decoder with native C-bindings for performance is Yajl: https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby

**UPD from @Stewart**:
`JSON.encode` is provided by rails as is `object.to_json`. For uses outside of rails use `JSON.generate` which is in ruby 1.9.3 std-lib. – Stewart

Comment: As mentioned, the `json` gem __does not allow encoding strings directly__. I'll take a look a Yajl.

Comment: For JSON gem compatibility in yajl you can do `require 'yajl/json_gem'`

Comment: It's worth noting that this answer assumes that the question poster is using rails(however this was not stipulated in the question). `JSON.encode` is provided by rails as is `object.to_json`. For uses outside of rails use `JSON.generate` which is in ruby 1.9.3 std-lib.

Comment: @Stewart comment should definitely be added to that answer imho